# Should API data be part of application state in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, state

I have a relatively small Redux & React application, however the API calls return relatively large chunks of data, that data conststitutes the biggest portion of application. Should the API data be part of the application state? If not - where to put it, if yes - how to manage it.

I have this application / UI state:

```
export let initialState = {
  pages: {
    browse: {
      filter: {
        favorites: false,
        inbasket: false
      },
      numOfItems: 20,
      url: '/browse'
    },
    item: {
      id: 1,
      url: '/item/1'
    }
  },
  currentPage: 'browse',
  favoriteItems: [1, 3, 5],
  inBasketItems: [6],
}
```

The browse page however has many items and each item has many attributes. Should the "all items" array be part of application state?

@dan-abramov

Comment: Yes, and when you start having performance issues, just start clearing the data you don't need.

Comment: As @RandomUser says, yes keep the data, but if you have performance issues only keep what you need. That or make new API methods to only get the data you need.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reference in any docs or a blog to this? I would like to know more